# Twitter typehead.js is showing the whole query and not just the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, node.js, typeahead.js

[My issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8FvY.png)

This is my code for the query. I am trying to get it to return just the value instead it is returning the whole query value.

```js
var engine;
engine = new Bloodhound({
  local: [{value: 'red'}, {value: 'blue'}, {value: 'green'}, {value: 'yellow'}, {value: 'violet'}, {value: 'brown'}, {value: 'purple'}, {value: 'black'}, {value: 'white'}],
  datumTokenizer: function (d) {
    return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.value);
  },
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace
});

engine.initialize();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using {value: color} hashes?

```
var engine;
engine = new Bloodhound({
  local: ['red','blue','green','yellow','violet','brown','purple','black','white'],
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rfuvtg5s/)

Comment: Thanks that seems to work not sure what the problem was unless it was the datumTokenizer function. Thanks again!